openpyxl preserving the style include checkboxes on named Styles
As a minimum example, I trying to open an excel document that has a custom named style saved into it. I am going to write some data out and then save the document as a different name. Unfortunately, whenever I do a save operation on a workbook (even immediately after loading with nothing else done) then the "style includes" checkboxes all check on,  in the named style in newly saved file, even though they are not all on in the initial file. The first image is the state of the "style includes" checkboxes in the original file (testStyle.xlsx) for my custom named style (myNewStyle):
custom named style in original excel file
However if I then save the file using openpyxl then open the new saved file then the state of those checkboxes will all the turned on, and I cannot find a way to control them. So those same checkboxes look like this in the new saved file:
custom named style has been altered in the saved file
This change can be reproduced using the following code on the test file linked here:
import openpyxl
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("testStyle.xlsx")  # Load the Excel with the custom style
workbook.save("newExcelFile.xlsx") # Immediately save the workbook to a new file name


The test file is completely empty with just one custom style added to try and explore the minimum case.
I am using Python 3.10 and openpyxl==3.1.5
I have tried the code above with the linked Excel file and the problem occurs as described. I have also tried loading and saving as a xlsm with "keep_vba=True" but this does not seem to change anything.
I have also looked into the named_styles (openpyxl.styles.named_styles.NamedStyle) and identified the named style in the file, but I cannot see anything in the class definition that would allow me to control those checkboxes.
Any help solving this would be amazing as I really need to be able to continue to manually work with the Excel file after the python has run without these styles being altered! Thank you for taking the time to read this, it is really appreciated :)
